# S. Weinberg, “The Quantum theory of fields: Foundations” (1995), Eq. (9.2.15)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, regularization

In Weinberg's book *The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1* on p.388 (Chapter 9), the following identity is used (with $f$ being any "reasonable" function):

$$f(+\infty) + f(-\infty) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\tau f(\tau) e^{-\epsilon |\tau|}.\tag{9.2.15} $$

I don't understand the identity in a qualitative / heuristic way.

Comment: Please describe what exactly You don't understand and why. It will be easier for people here to help You.

Comment: [Final value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand the identity qualitatively now:

If the function f(t) has a well defined value at $t = \pm\infty$, then for large values of $|t|$ the function f is essentially constant with values $f(-\infty)$ for $t < 0$ and $f(+\infty)$ for $t > 0$.

For tiny $\epsilon$ the Exponential factor $e^{-\epsilon |t|}$ is essentially equal to $1$ for  $|t| < 1 / \epsilon $, and almost Zero for large $|t| > 1 / \epsilon$.

We then have approximately: $\epsilon\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}t \, f(t) e^{-\epsilon |t|} \approx \epsilon\int_{1 / \epsilon}^0 \mathrm{d}t \, f(-\infty) + \epsilon\int_0^{1 / \epsilon} \mathrm{d}t \, f(+\infty) = f(-\infty) + f(+\infty)$

Comment: I know this comment is a decade too late, but I think the argument here misses a key piece of intuition. Namely, say $f(t)$ is well approximated by its asymptotic value $f(\infty)$ for $t>T$. Then really we should have have $\epsilon \int_0^T dt f(t) + \epsilon \int_T^{1/\epsilon} dt f(+\infty)=\epsilon \int_0^T f(t)+f(+\infty)$ in the last equation. In the first integral, from $0$ to $T$, $f(t)$ is not well approximated by $f(+\infty)$. However, $\epsilon$ can be taken small enough that this term becomes arbitrarily small with respect to the second. The same argument applies for negative $t$.

Answer (score 10):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I &= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} \tau \, f(\tau) e^{- \epsilon |\tau| } \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{0} \mathrm{d}\tau \, f(\tau) e^{\epsilon \tau } + \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \epsilon \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}\tau \, f(\tau) e^{- \epsilon \tau } \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{-\infty}^{0} \mathrm{d}\tau\, f(\tau) \partial_\tau e^{\epsilon \tau } -\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}\tau\,  f(\tau) \partial_\tau e^{- \epsilon \tau } \\
&= - \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{-\infty}^{0} \mathrm{d}\tau \, \partial_\tau  f(\tau) e^{\epsilon \tau } + \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}\tau \, \partial_\tau f(\tau)  e^{- \epsilon \tau }  + 2 f(0) \\
&= -  \int_{-\infty}^{0} \mathrm{d}\tau \, \partial_\tau  f(\tau)   + \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}\tau \, \partial_\tau f(\tau) + 2 f(0) \\
&= (- f(0) + f(-\infty) ) + (f(\infty) - f(0) ) + 2 f( 0 ) \\
&= f(\infty) + f(-\infty)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

Assume that the limit $f(\infty):= \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists.

1. *Method 1:*  Assume that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable. Assume that $f\geq 0$ is monotone on $\mathbb{R}_+$ or assume that the net $t \mapsto f(t/\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$ has an integrable majorant on $\mathbb{R}_+$. Then $$
   \begin{align}\epsilon\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~f(t)~\theta(t)e^{-\epsilon t} 
   ~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~f(t/\epsilon)~\theta(t)e^{-t} \cr
   ~\longrightarrow~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~f(\infty)~\theta(t)e^{-t}\cr 
   ~=~&f(\infty)\quad\text{for}\quad\epsilon\to 0^+.\tag{1}\end{align}$$
2. *Method 2:*  Assume that $f$ is differentiable and $f^{\prime}$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}_+$. Then 
   $$\begin{align}\epsilon\int_0^{\infty}\!dt~f(t)~e^{-\epsilon t} 
   ~=~& - \int_0^{\infty}\!dt~f(t)~\frac{d}{dt}e^{-\epsilon t}\cr
   ~\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}{=}&~\int_0^{\infty}\!dt~f^{\prime}(t)e^{-\epsilon t}-\left[f(t)~e^{-\epsilon t} \right]_0^{\infty}\cr
   ~\longrightarrow~&\int_0^{\infty}\!dt~f^{\prime}(t) +f(0) \cr 
   ~=~&f(\infty)\quad\text{for}\quad\epsilon\to 0^+.\tag{2}\end{align}$$
3. *Method 3:*  (Method 2 rewritten with distributions.) 
   $$\begin{align}\epsilon\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~f(t)~\theta(t)e^{-\epsilon t} 
   ~=~& - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~f(t)~\theta(t)\frac{d}{dt}e^{-\epsilon t}\cr
   ~\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}{=}&~\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~e^{-\epsilon t}\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)~\theta(t))\cr
   ~\longrightarrow~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)~\theta(t))\cr
   ~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~\frac{df(t)}{dt}\theta(t)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dt~f(t) \delta(t) \cr
   ~=~&f(\infty)\quad\text{for}\quad\epsilon\to 0^+.\tag{3}\end{align}$$