# Is Formula (9.2.15) in Weinberg true?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Weinberg Vol. I (9.2.15) writes:
$$f(+\infty)+f(-\infty) = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\epsilon\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!d\tau\,f(\tau)e^{-\epsilon|\tau|}\;.\tag{9.2.15}$$
But I can't prove this formula, nor can I get it to work numerically.
Here is the value of such an integral (y-axis) vs. $-\log_{10}\epsilon$ (x-axis):

[image]

The actual value is supposed to be 2. There is a little bump at $I=2$ but no convergence. I used $f(x) = 1+ \tanh(x/2) + \exp(-x^2/4)$.

Comment: Suggested possible solution: integrate by parts ($u=f$, $dv = e^{-\epsilon|\tau|} dx$), and see what assumptions about $f$ and the limits are needed to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105327/2451