# Stuck on proof of $\epsilon$ prescription of integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, regularization

\begin{equation}
f(\infty)+f(-\infty)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt f(t) e^{-\epsilon|t|}\tag{9.2.15}
\end{equation}
I assume this is a smooth function $f(\tau)$ that intuitively this relation holds, but unable to proof this. This is given in Weinberg and Schwartz book, but I am not able to prove this relation

Comment: Try to substitute $x:=\epsilon t$.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to do a specific numerical example to get some intuition, such as $f$ being piecewise constant: [see wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=epsilon+*+%28integral+of+A+*+e%5E%28t*epsilon%29+from+-inf+to+0+%2B+integral+of+B+*+e%5E%28-t*epsilon%29+from+0+to+inf+%29).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105327/2451